# Swift compiler bug maybe?

Tags: uiview, swift, uiviewanimation

i want to do the simplest animation in swift

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration, animations: { () -> Void in
        return
    })
```

but i'm getting  Missing argument for parameter 'delay' in call

any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried adding a parameter for "delay"?

Comment: yes basically added all the params the problem is with UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration

Answer (score 4):

`UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration` is a `Float`, but the `duration:`
parameter has the type `NSTimeInterval` (which is an alias for `Double`). Therefore you have
to convert explicitly:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration), animations: { () -> Void in
    return
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The UIView class method [animateWithdDuration:animations:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:) is defined as:

`class func animateWithDuration(_ duration: NSTimeInterval,
                    animations animations: () -> Void)`

Note the first parameter has a type of NSTimeInterval, while the [UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration) is a constant of type CGFloat:

`let UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration: CGFloat`

Checking the [documentation for NSTimeInterval](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSTimeInterval) shows that in Swift it is a TypeAlias for a Double

`typealias NSTimeInterval = Double`

So we must get our CGFloat converted to a Double to make the call work.
We can create a Double easily from a CGFloat by `Double(UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration)`

It is probably better to use `NSTimeInterval(UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration)`
to ensure that the type signature matches for readers of your code.